# CheckedChanged Event in a Gridview checkbox to update hidden labels

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, gridview

I have a gridview where the first column are check boxes, the next column is ID's.  I have hidden labels on the page that need to get the current ID for any check boxes checked.  The labels are specific, hlbl_pain1, hlbl_pain2, hlbl_pain3.  It doenst matter which label gets which ID I just need each of the 3 hidden labels to be populated with ID's.  Right now on CheckedChanged the 3 labels all update with the same value.  I'm having issues looping.  This is in VB.

Here's my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_pain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ds_grid_pain"  ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" style="text-align: left; font-size: x-small; ">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPain" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPain_CheckedChanged"  />  
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("DrugID")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DrugID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="DrugID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DrugID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_DrugID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DrugID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NickName" HeaderText="NickName" SortExpression="NickName" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DrugName" HeaderText="DrugName" SortExpression="DrugName" ItemStyle-Width="500px">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quan1" HeaderText="Quan1" SortExpression="Quan1">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quan2" HeaderText="Quan2" SortExpression="Quan2">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Here are my labels:

```
 <asp:Label ID="hlbl_pain1" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="hlbl_pain2" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="hlbl_pain3" runat="server"  Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in my CheckedChanged in the codebehind:

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxPain_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim row As GridViewRow

For Each row In gv_pain.Rows

    Dim cbPain As CheckBox = row.FindControl("CheckBoxPain")
    If cbPain.Checked = True Then
        Dim lblDrugID As Label = row.FindControl("lbl_DrugID")
        hlbl_pain1.Text = lblDrugID.text
    End If


    Dim cbPain1 As CheckBox = row.FindControl("CheckBoxPain")
    If cbPain1.Checked = True Then
        Dim lblDrugID As Label = row.FindControl("lbl_DrugID")
        hlbl_pain2.Text = lblDrugID.text
    End If


    Dim cbPain2 As CheckBox = row.FindControl("CheckBoxPain")
    If cbPain2.Checked = True Then
        Dim lblDrugID As Label = row.FindControl("lbl_DrugID")
        hlbl_pain3.Text = lblDrugID.text
    End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you see any difference between `row.FindControl("CheckBoxPain")` & `row.FindControl("CheckBoxPain")` so how come you can expect any different value in `cbPain` & `cbPain1`?

Comment: I don't, but because it was referencing a checkbox in a template field with only one name "CheckBoxPain" I thought that might be how it had to be called.  Evidently the value stays the same, it doesn't change with the loop.

Comment: Okay so what you are trying to do? Whenever user clicks on checkbox it should automatically postback and set the all the three labels with value present in `lbl_DrugID`?

Comment: Let's assume the user can only select 3 checkboxes in this gridview (i'll handle the max of 3).  I would like the labels hlbl_pain1, hlbl_pain2, hlbl_pain3 each hold the ID from the row of the checked checkboxes.  A user could check and uncheck boxes so I need the label values to stay in sync with the current checked boxes.  Yes, lbl_DrugID is the ID field of the gridview.

Comment: Okay check my answer. I am afraid it will again give you same result because each time the event is triggered you will overwrite the value. Please debug and understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: It's close... I have the 3 different labels I'm trying to update.  I haven't figured out how to get the latest checked value into hlbl_pain1, hlbl_pain2, or hlbl_pain3.  Also, when a checkbox is unchecked, I need to set the label with it's value to empty, and then use that label for the next selected value.  Thoughts?

Comment: It's not clear to me. Why you want to blank that out? The next time user will check any checkbox it will anyways update the value in label. Also, I don't think its possible to do the `recent` thing.

Comment: I have 3 different hidden labels, I need to store each of the currently checked values in them.  I don't understand how to update hlbl_pain1, hlbl_pain2, or hlbl_pain3 in a good way.

Comment: I can certainly help you with that but if I again update my answer you may have some different expectation. I am not sure why you are storing these values in hidden variable? What you are trying to achieve. If I will understand that I may help you.